# Making sure same javascript files are not downloaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to develop an embeddable widget. This widget renders some UI elements into the customer's page.

This widget will look like this:

```
<script src="//example.com/widget.js?param1=a&param2=b" async></script>
```

A user is allowed to embed multiple widgets on a single page, each with a different set of parameters.

Within this widget script, I am trying to load other javascript and css files required to render my widget.

This is the function I am using to load other javascript files.

```
function loadScript(scriptUrl) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.src = scriptUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

The problem is that each script loaded this way is loaded multiple times, when there are more than one embeds per page.

How do I make sure each file is loaded only once? 
For example,  I try to load a jQuery reference inside that loader script, I see that if I embed my widget 5 times, there are 5 calls to the jquery library.

Comment: record what is loaded and check before loading? Use tagged it with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), why are you not using it?

Comment: if you are loading a jquery plugin or any group of function, you can check if the function exist before loading your script. example : `if(typeof yourFunctionName == 'function')`.

Answer (score 1):

3 extra lines of code

```
var scripts = {};  //record what is loaded
function loadScript(scriptUrl) {
    if (scripts[scriptUrl]) return;  //exit if loaded
    scripts[scriptUrl] = 1;  //mark that it is loaded
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.src = scriptUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering - why use an array, and not an object literal? I know it's basically the same thing in the way you are using it (like an associative array), and it's used very minimally, I just didn't know if there was a reason for using `[]` and not `{}`. Also, why not use `if (scriptUrl in scripts)` ? Nonetheless, a great solution, I'd say

Comment: This did not work for me. I can still see that there are multiple requests made to a file that is loaded.

Comment: @ashwnacharya Is the scriptURL exact? Are you counting scripts that are loaded not with this method? Without seeing why it is not working, I can just guess it is something else.